# Date validation from form input with PHP

Tags: php, html, date

I have a form with HTML code like this:

```
<div>          
     <label for="dateCheckin">Date Checking in</label>
     <input type="date" name="dateCheckin">          
</div>
```

And I try to check if the date selected is at least 2 weeks from the current date using PHP. Put when I run the code, there is an undefined index: dateCheckin.

```
$checkinDate = strtotime($_POST['dateCheckin']);

if ($checkinDate){
    $today = time();
    $diff = $checkinDate->diff($today)->days;
    $diff /= 7;
    $diff = floor($diff);
    if ($diff < 2){
        echo "Please enter a valid date.";
    }
    
} else{
    echo "Please enter a valid date.";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you might be running this using PHP-CLI? Try using PHP built in web server and run. `php -S localhost:8000 <filename>.php`. Additionally, you're going to have problems posting with no form element. I'd advice you take a look at the following: [Posting Data with PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_superglobals_post.asp)

Comment: Probably its not using post Method use a form element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I recommend you to use `DateTime()` object instead of `time()` function.

```
$checkinDate = new DateTime('2021-05-14 09:52:52'); //use your actual POST value here

if ($checkinDate){
    $today = new DateTime();
    $diff = $checkinDate->diff($today);
    $days= $diff->format('%a');

    if($days>14){
        echo "2 Weeks done. Please enter a new date";
    }
    else{
        echo "Not done 2 weeks yet.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are tricky and you're kinda doing it the hardest way.

I highly recommend using the `DateTime` object, and you'll end up something like this:

```php
$checkinDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_POST['dateCheckin']);

if ($checkinDate) {
    $twoWeeksDate = new DateTime('now + 2 weeks');
    if($checkinDate < $twoWeeksDate) {
        echo "Please select a date date before: " . $twoWeeksDate->format('d/m/Y');
    }
} else {
    echo "Please enter a valid date.";
}
```

Be sure to change the date format to be the correct format for your inputs and outputs.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed my code based on your solution, however, there is still an undefined index error. Do you have any idea why this error happens?

Comment: either your `$_POST` variable doesn't have a key `dateCheckin` and you need to correct it to something else, or some other array has the same problem. `Undefined Index` just means you're trying to access an array by a key, or index, that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Tran if this did solve your question as asked, please accept this answer so others with the same question can know this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your data not passing into POST method, So you get a undefined index error

```
<form action="Your Action page" Method="POST">
   <label for="dateCheckin">Date Checking in</label>
     <input type="date" name="dateCheckin">
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```